# Calling an intent with result from a non-activity class based on click listener

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-view

So, I know you should not call an intent from a non-Activity class, let alone an intent with a result. A non-Activity class simply shouldn't do that and be responsible for whatever it's supposed to do.

#### What I have

Now, I have a `NappingActivity`, which displays a dozen buttons, implemented in `VideoButtonView`. These buttons extend `android.widget.Button`.

I want to be able to drag and click the buttons, so I implemented the drag / click logic in the `VideoButtonView`, by setting:

```
this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { … }
```

And when a user clicks the button inside `onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)`, the following is called:

```
Context context = v.getContext();
Intent showVideo = new Intent(context, ViewActivity.class);
context.startActivity(showVideo);
```

So far, so good.

#### What I want

Now, this intent returns to the `NappingActivity`, but I'd like to separare this video playing intent by returning a result. So, ideally, I'd call this `startActivityForResult` from the `NappingActivity`, and not the `VideoButtonView`, because the latter isn't possible anyway.

#### Questions

- How do I go about refactoring this, so I can handle the click from within the activity rather than the button, or at least send the intent from there?
- Should I move the whole click and drag logic to the activity? Doesn't sound very clean.
- Can I implement some kind of custom listeners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I go about refactoring this, so I can handle the click from
>   within the activity rather than the button, or at least send the
>   intent from there?

You could implement a callback system. See third answer.

> Should I move the whole click and drag logic to the activity? Doesn't
>   sound very clean.

No, you're mixing logic(But I don't understood how you implement the drag system so I may be wrong).

> Can I implement some kind of custom listeners?

Create interface:

```
public interface StartVideoListener {
    public void onStartVideoRequest(int buttonId); 
}
```

Let your `NappingActivity` implement this interface:

```
public class NappingActivity extends Activity implements StartVideoListener {

    // ...
    public void onStartVideoRequest(int buttonId) {
        // you know the button that was clicked, start the desired activity.
    }
```

In the `VideoButtonView` class cast the `Context` from the constructor to a `StartVideoListener` field and call its method in `onTouch`:

```
// ...
mListener.onStartVideoRequest(v.getId());
```